# Is crashing common with version 3.5?

Tags: shaders

I've been experiencing a frequent and troubling phenomenon. Often when I am in Shading, when I go to add a new material Blender crashes. I have been using my current laptop computer - an HP Envy 17, 64 bit with 16 GB of RAM and an NVIDIA GeForce MX330 - for a while now, and previous versions of Blender didn't crash during the Shading process, even when I had a good number of memory-hungry materials and textures applied. I'm curious if anyone else has had this experience, and if it's something specific to this current version of blender. Thanks for any insights.

Comment: 3.5 isn't supported now, but there weren't any specific problems with it to my knowledge. Worth checking that your graphics drivers are up to date. 3.6.5 is the current long term supported version and 4.0.1 is the latest version but may not work with your graphics card.